How to Move Objects away from each other (Scale the Distance) in Geometry Nodes?
I have the following setup and would love it if someone could show me what nodes to use, so I can move these three objects away from each other by scaling the distance between them along the X,Y axis.
enter link description here


how should they move? from 0/0/0 in direction to their median point?

@Chris Probably in the same way as in the question he asked earlier, but using Geometry Nodes!

@JohnEason: tbh the linked questions confuses me even more, because the arrows  track to another direction than i would have expected....but hopefully it is that what he wants.

Hey @JohnEason you are correct, I have decided that node control over this movement would be better for my project, so I'm hoping to deepen my understanding for how to use GN to perform this same function.

if the should move along 0/0/0 and their median point, you can create this node group:

which calculates the median point of each geometry, scales it by the input value and then offsets the geometry. Then use it like so:

if you wanna move them all, you could use this setup:


Thanks Chris.  I've followed this to the letter but for some reason in my project (not the dumbed down version I posted) the objects aren't moving equal distant from each other, even though each object is identical, with origin at 0,0,0.  I will edit my question with more information shortly, thanks for taking the time to help me, I definitely learned a thing ;)

I stand corrected. I changed the Attribute Statistic node from Median to Mean and that did the trick. I don't really understand what's going on here, but it's working and will get me through my project, so in this case that's enough!  Thanks again ;)
